# How do you give limbs of a character symmetry?

Tags: modeling

I used the mirror modifier to give the character symmetry but I can't really apply the same for the arms and legs as they're already part of the character with the mirror modifier. Do I separate the limbs and give them the mirror modifier or is there another solution?

[image]

As seen from the feet, one side of the feet has faces while the other does not.

Comment: hello, it's a bit hard to understand, could you please show a screenshot?

Comment: sure, i don't know how to add a screenshot to a reply but i'll edit the thread real quick

Comment: do you mean that the mirrored leg already exists and now it's doubled because of the Mirror modifier? In that case you need to delete so that it's only mirrored by the modifier

Comment: the faces are missing in one side of the feet while the other side has them. i'm just kinda unsure how to mirror the feet so they are symmetrical

Comment: you could apply the mirror, fix the problem on the side you want, then delete the other half and mirror again? but maybe share your file (or at least a part like the legs): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i'll give it a try. thanks :-)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6kKrVwMy" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6kKrVwMy/)

Comment: I can't see the problem, there is no vertex in the other side, you just have an inner face that you probably need to delete but other than that you can go on this way, or maybe reformulate your question because I may be missing something

Comment: Hello. The model does not show any issue (except an inner face). So the question is very unclear, please try to edit your question indicating exactly what you want to do or what the issue is.

Comment: you say "As seen from the feet, one side of the feet has faces while the other does not", if you want each limb to be symmetrical, yes you need to make it a different object and give it its own Mirror modifier

Comment: if you want to flip a part of a mesh, select it and press S X (or another axis) -1

Comment: ah okay, thanks everyone!